# Enumeration Referencing not working properly

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx, enumitem

I started working with LyX and until now I'm really impressed.
I have a problem when referencing to enumeration items of resumed enumerations. The references in the output don't give the right number of the enumeration.
My input looks like this:

[image]

Code of my Lyx-File:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true

\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
enumitem
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding utf8-cjk
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #718c00
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Enumerate
Test
\end_layout

\begin_deeper
\begin_layout Enumerate
Test2
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "enu:Test2"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Enumerate
Test3
\end_layout

\end_deeper
\begin_layout Standard
Referencing Test2 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand ref
reference "enu:Test2"
plural "false"
caps "false"
noprefix "false"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Enumerate-Resume
Test4
\end_layout

\begin_deeper
\begin_layout Enumerate-Resume
Test5
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "enu:Test5"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Enumerate-Resume
Test6
\end_layout

\end_deeper
\begin_layout Standard
Referencing Test5 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand ref
reference "enu:Test5"
plural "false"
caps "false"
noprefix "false"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Enumerate-Resume
Test7
\end_layout

\begin_deeper
\begin_layout Enumerate-Resume
Test8
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "enu:Test8"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Enumerate-Resume
Test9
\end_layout

\end_deeper
\begin_layout Standard
Referencing Test8 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand ref
reference "enu:Test8"
plural "false"
caps "false"
noprefix "false"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

This is the LaTeX preview source code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\newlength{\lyxlabelwidth}      % auxiliary length 

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test2\label{enu:Test2}
\item Test3
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Referencing Test2 \ref{enu:Test2}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Test4
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Test5\label{enu:Test5}
\item Test6
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Referencing Test5 \ref{enu:Test5}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Test7
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Test8\label{enu:Test8}
\item Test9
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Referencing Test8 \ref{enu:Test8}
\end{document}
```

While my Output looks like this:
[image]

As you can see the Reference to Test5 should output 2a. But it results in 1a. 3a results in a 2a reference. When enablig hyperref support, the links in the pdf jump to the right position, but the number is still wrong.

I already tried different positions for the label etc. but nothing seems to help.
What am I doing wrong? Does anyone have a tip?

Comment: We'll need the code, not a screenshot :)

Comment: I added the code of the Lyx-File. Hope this is the code from the right file.

Comment: Looks like the right code, yes. A lot of people around don't use LyX though. If you add the complete LaTeX code from the preview pane (View -> Code preview pane, and then choose "Complete source" in the dropdown menu in the pane), that increases the chance of getting a reply about the LaTeX side of things at least.

Comment: LaTeX code is added. I hope that this helps so that someone can at least determine the problem on LaTeX side.

Comment: @liha: Remove the nested `[resume]`. It seems like you've just added `resume` as an option to every `enumerate`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments! @Werner: This was the decisive hint to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Werner's post was the answer!

Removing the `[resume]` for all nested items solved the problem.
To do this in LyX it is necessary to use the Enumeration style instead of the Enumeration-Resume style for nested items to get a proper referencing.